# "undefined" is displayed when inserting HTML element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a google chrome extension that attempts to insert an HTML element into a webpage with javascript. Here is what the html looks like on the browser[image]

As you can see, under No Recent Updates there is the string "undefined" there. I inspected the html to see where exactly this string was located. Here is the html portion.[image]

The H3 Tag is the element I am inserting. It includes a p tag, as well as a div that contains a table. However, in that div, "undefined" is there and I'm not sure why. It's located in the div tag before the table tag, but I don't have anything in that area in javascript code.

```
    chrome.storage.local.get("tr", function(key){
    var new_tr = "";
    var tr = key.tr;


    for (i=changes.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        var td = "";
        for (j=0; j<changes[i].length; j++){
            td += "<td align='left'>"+changes[i][j]+"</td>";
        }
        new_tr ="<tr>"+td+"</tr>" + new_tr;
    }



    var historybox = document.createElement("h3");
    var tableHTML = "<div style='overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px;'><table><tr><td>Subject</td><td>Tri</td><td>Before</td><td>After</td><td>Change</td><td>Date Updated</td></tr>" + new_tr + tr + "</table></div>";
    if (changes.length == 0){
        tableHTML = "<p>No Recent Updates</p>" + tableHTML;
    } 

    historybox.innerHTML = tableHTML;

    var contentArea = document.getElementById("content-main");
    var box = contentArea.querySelector("h1");
    contentArea.insertBefore(box.cloneNode(true), box);
    contentArea.replaceChild(historybox, box);


    chrome.storage.local.set({'tr' : (new_tr+tr)})

});
```

This is the code I use to insert the HTML. If we look at where it says *var tableHTML = ...* There is absolutely nothing between the div and table tag. What could be causing this problem

Comment: please share html code

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the contents of whatever you're retrieving from localStorage, so I can't be certain, but it seems likely that your `tr` variable contains an undefined value (and when you try to insert it into the table without a containing `<td>` or `<tr>` it gets bumped outside the table, because `<table>` tags can't directly contain non-table markup.)

```js
// Guesses at your source data:
changes = [
  ["one", "two", "three"]
];

var new_tr = "";
var tr = undefined;

// your (unmodified) code below:

for (i = changes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var td = "";
  for (j = 0; j < changes[i].length; j++) {
    td += "<td align='left'>" + changes[i][j] + "</td>";
  }
  new_tr = "<tr>" + td + "</tr>" + new_tr;
}

var historybox = document.createElement("h3");
var tableHTML = "<div style='overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px;'><table><tr><td>Subject</td><td>Tri</td><td>Before</td><td>After</td><td>Change</td><td>Date Updated</td></tr>" + new_tr + tr + "</table></div>";
if (changes.length == 0) {
  tableHTML = "<p>No Recent Updates</p>" + tableHTML;
}

historybox.innerHTML = tableHTML;

var contentArea = document.getElementById("content-main");
var box = contentArea.querySelector("h1");
contentArea.insertBefore(box.cloneNode(true), box);
contentArea.replaceChild(historybox, box);
```

```html
<div id="content-main">
<h1>header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, tr was indeed an undefined value. When running the chrome extension for the first time, the local storage is empty and there fore anything returned is undefined.